# What is the structure of a bitmap in Pebble-SDK on basalt

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Using [graphics_capture_frame_buffer](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/Graphics/Drawing_Primitives/#graphics_capture_frame_buffer) a GBitmap is returned.  What is the format of this if I wanted to work with it directly. How would I modify a single pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pebble 3.0 you can use the `gbitmap_*` accessors:

- [`gbitmap_get_data()`](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/Graphics/Graphics_Types/#gbitmap_get_data) to get the bytes of data
- [`gbitmap_get_format()`](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/Graphics/Graphics_Types/#gbitmap_get_format) to confirm the format of the Bitmap (should be 8bit per pixel on Basalt)
- [`gbitmap_get_bytes_per_row()`](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/Graphics/Graphics_Types/#gbitmap_get_bytes_per_row) to get the number of bytes in each row

When the format is `GBitmapFormat8Bit`, each pixel is one byte in ARGB (2bits per component).

Comment: Thank you! Helped me to finally achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29173750/961695 (though still not sure if this is the best approach)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the [isometric](https://github.com/pebble-hacks/isotime) example given in the SDK. So it would appear to be one uint8_t per pixel a row at a time holding the ARGB at 2 bits each.

```c
#define GColorFromRGB ((GColor8){ \ .a = 3, \ .r = (uint8_t)(red) >> 6, \ .g = (uint8_t)(green) >> 6, \ .b = (uint8_t)(blue) >> 6, \ })

static void set_pixel(GPoint pixel, GColor color) {
  if(pixel.x >= 0 && pixel.x < 144 && pixel.y >= 0 && pixel.y < 168) {
    memset(&s_fb_data[(pixel.y * s_fb_size.w) + pixel.x], (uint8_t)color.argb, 1);
  }
}
```